# String Array value can not pass through function

Tags: excel, vba

Both the functions are not work when I pass array value as string e.g.

Error generated : Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch

```
 If SheetExists(StruArr(R, 2)) Then Sheets(StruArr(R, 2)).Delete
```

```
Public Function SheetExists(strSheetName As String, Optional wbWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean
    If wbWorkbook Is Nothing Then Set wbWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook - whichever appropriate
    Dim obj As Object
    On Error GoTo HandleError
    Set obj = wbWorkbook.Sheets(strSheetName)
    SheetExists = True
    Exit Function
HandleError:
    SheetExists = False
End Function
```

```
Function ChkWs(ws As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ret As Boolean
    ret = False
    wsName = UCase(wsName)
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If UCase(ws.Name) = wsName Then
            ret = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    ChkWs = ret
End Function
```

If I use direct text e.g.

```
     If SheetExists("abcd") Then Sheets("abcd").Delete
```

It will work perfectly.

Comment: What is the data type for `StruArr`?

Comment: You are grabbing several rows by two or more columns into **StruArr** correct? If you are only grabbing one column then you are making a mistake in the rank.

Comment: okay first mistake found struArr is Variant.  But when I change in Function strSheetName As Variant instead of String. At the first line of function  **If strSheetName Is Nothing Then**  occurs error "Object Require"

Comment: You can fix that easily with a `CStr` wrapper.e.g. `If SheetExists(CStr(StruArr(R, 2))) Then...`

Comment: How do you populate struArr?.  And what is the subtype?

Comment: Dim StruArr() As Variant
StruArr = Range("A2:D" & GrpRows)
For R = 1 To UBound(StruArr, 1) 
    If SheetExists(CStr(StruArr(R, 2))) Then Sheets(StruArr(R, 2)).Delete
    .
    .

Comment: If SheetExists(CStr(StruArr(R, 2))) Then..... work!

Comment: Your original code, with StruArr declared as a variant, and strSheetname as string, and some sheet name in one of the cells, works here without an issue.  Something else is going on.  Is the contents of your range merely a sheetname string?  Is struArr(x,y) a simple string?

Comment: yes. To create dynamically worksheets I use this and even in Immediate Windows I check the value of ?struArr(x,y) it shows simple text e.g. exp, income,...

Comment: Hmmm.  Well, I guess without looking at the workbook itself, I'm not going to be able to figure out why the code errors at your location, yet runs OK here.  If you want to upload the version that shows the error to some sharing site (with sensitive information removed), and post a link here, I'd be glad to take a look.  But I understand you may not want to do that, especially since you seem to have things working.  Up to you.